# Creating Nested Labels in Gmail using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, arraylist, gmail, label

I'm trying to create a set of nested labels from a column of values in a spreadsheet. I've gotten my array situated, and I can create a single Label/sub-label with the following syntax:
GmailApp.createLabel("Label/sub-label").

Looking at the last line of code, how can I rewrite this to produce a sub-label for each value in my array under the Parent Label "Clients"? The error I receive currently is:
The parameters (String,number[]) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.createLabel.

```
function clientLabels(){
  /** List of Clients */
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BWutWGYPW9RjewRNdgLdHCn-Rytbyi63xbPF2Hd3tPg")
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Company")
    const range = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1)
    const values = range.getValues()

  /** Creating Labels */
    GmailApp.createLabel("Clients")
    GmailApp.createLabel("Clients/%s", values))
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to enter a number array as a string. In my solution you will break the array in individual values and will execute the function for every individual value.

```
/** List of Clients */
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BWutWGYPW9RjewRNdgLdHCn-Rytbyi63xbPF2Hd3tPg")
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Company")
  const range = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1)
  const values = range.getValues()

/** Creating Labels */
  GmailApp.createLabel("Clients")

  values.forEach(function(value) {
    GmailApp.createLabel("Clients/" + value[0].toString());
  });
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the dummy information, it looks like the array that **.getValues()** returned was a 2D array with one dimension being 1 in length. The code needed little change and now it should not. I changed the way the data is accessed from the array and removed the '%s' you had initially in favor of just concatenating the value.

Comment: Dummy Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CqZSMtSsxzYZwgq5XlwWxN_vSfpgP35rSV0dnCVLeVU/edit#gid=0
I'm getting a slightly different error: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.createLabel.

Comment: It appears the Array had an additional dimension, it was corrected by specifying the first index of the array. Note the value is now concatenated and the %s was removed.

Comment: Thank you Juan!! Syntax errors are always the hardest to figure out for me, thank you for explaining it so clearly!